# C#: Code is creating unwanted child nodes in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, listview

Piece of code I'm working with here is almost perfect accept I'm doing something wrong with the iteration piece I think. Items from the ListView are not becoming separate and distinct nodes in the XML file. Each subsequent item is becoming a child node of the first item in the ListView. What am I doing wrong? Code as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\database.xml", null);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Database");
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Account");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Description", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Username", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Password", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);

        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write out the `Account` end element - This should do it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Account");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Description", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Username", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Password", listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have WriteEndElement inside you for loop to close "Account node.